# How do I get the last message sent in a channel? | discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I already know how to grab the last message sent. However, it keeps grabbing the message sent to execute the command. For example, if initiating the comment is by writing in the channel `!test` then the last message sent would be `!test`. I need the actual last message sent, which is the one before it.

Code:

```
let last = "";
let lastMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 });
lastMessage.each((msg) => {
    last = msg.content; 
})
```

I've tried setting the limit to `2` in hopes that it would grab both the command sent to initiate the function and the previous message sent itself. However, I do not know how to differentiate between the two to grab the actual previous message as `msg.content` just returns the command `!test`.

Comment: I'd guess that the messages are returned in the order they appeared. So, after you fetch the two messages, the one you want would be `lastMessage[0].content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`limit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) option to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) the last two messages in a channel, it returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection). These messages are sorted in descending order, based on the date they were posted. It means, the first item in the returned collection is the last message sent (the one with the command), the second item is the second last message (the last one before the command).

Collections have methods like [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) and [`last()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=last) that return the first and last items respectively.

```js
let lastMessages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 });
// this is the last message sent before this command
let previousMessage = lastMessages.last();

message.reply(`The last message was _"${previousMessage.content}"_`);
message.reply(
  `Is the first fetched message (i.e. \`lastMessages.first()\`) the same as this message?\n ${
    message.id === lastMessages.first().id ? '✅ yes' : '❌ no'
  }`,
);
```

[image]